# Why doesn't this return type work? (C++)

Tags: c++, subclass, return-type

When I try to use my iterator class

```
template<class T>
class list
{
public:
class iterator;
};

template<class T>
class list<T>::iterator
{
//stuff
};
```

as a return type in an operator overloading,

```
template<class T>
class list<T>::iterator
{
public:
iterator& operator++();
protected:
list* lstptr;
};

template<class T>
iterator& list<T>::iterator::operator++()
{
(this->lstptr)->current = ((this->lstptr)->current)->next;
return this;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
s:\jeffrey_\my_freeware_games\o\resources\container class\container(spec- o)\container_def.h(213) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
s:\jeffrey_\my_freeware_games\o\resources\container class\container(spec- o)\container_def.h(213) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
s:\jeffrey_\my_freeware_games\o\resources\container class\container(spec- o)\container_def.h(213) : error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(235) : error C2039: 'Yes' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(235) : error C2065: 'Yes' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(236) : error C2039: 'No' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(236) : error C2065: 'No' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(237) : error C2039: 'Maybe' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(237) : error C2065: 'Maybe' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(240) : error C2039: 'NoAccess' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(240) : error C2065: 'NoAccess' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(241) : error C2039: 'Read' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(241) : error C2065: 'Read' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(242) : error C2039: 'Write' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(242) : error C2065: 'Write' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(243) : error C2039: 'ReadWrite' : is not a member of 'vc_attributes'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(243) : error C2065: 'ReadWrite' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(582) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'time_t'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(2047) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'identifier'
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(2047) : warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'localeinfo_struct' when no variable is declared
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(2047) : fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(174)' was matched
```

NB: container_def.h is the header file for my list and iterator classes, I have no idea what souceannotations or crtdefs are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iterator` is not yet known at that point. You need to tell it it's in the `list<T>` class:

```
template<class T>
typename list<T>::iterator& list<T>::iterator::operator++() {
    (this->lstptr)->current = ((this->lstptr)->current)->next;
    return *this; // *this here, since this is a pointer only
}
```

Notice the `typename` is required, since `list<T>::iterator` is a type prefixed with a template specialization, and you need to tell the compiler about that - in spite of the fact that Visual C++ probably will accept code not putting `typename` before it. Omitting the `typename`, the compiler should assume it's not a type and should sort of produce the same error message.

You could safe yourself that hassle by putting the code straight into the class:

```
template<class T>
class list<T>::iterator
{
public:
iterator& operator++() {
    (this->lstptr)->current = ((this->lstptr)->current)->next;
    return *this; // *this here, since this is a pointer only
}
protected:
    list* lstptr;
};
```

Comment: Yep, typename is definitely what I was looking for, (I didn't know it existed) I tried using list<T>::iterator&, but the compiler told me it didn't recognize that as a type.

Comment: Oh nice. Seems like the compiler does require it at some places actually. In some posts i've seen people using msvc++ are not required to put it at certain places where it is needed normally :)

Answer (score 1):

litb has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891066/why-doesnt-this-return-type-work-c/891076#891076) your question completely.  I think it worth highlighting that in an effort to make C++ easier to use, the C++ Committee has added a new syntax for the declaration of functions.  The result is that you'll be able to define your function as follows ([n2541](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2541.htm)) without needing the extra qualification:

```
template<class T>
auto list<T>::iterator::operator++()->iterator& 
{
  // ...
}
```

According to the supported feature [list](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), GCC 4.4 already has this feature.